# Are spaces around CSS combinators are really optional

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm a bit confused by using CSS selectors with axis combinators in BeautifulSoup. Below is the simple code to illustrate what I mean:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python')
soup = bs(response.text)

print(len(soup.select('#mainbar > div')))
```

returns `6` children... but

```
print(len(soup.select('#mainbar>div')))
```

returns `0` children...

The same with `'#mainbar ~ div'` (found 1 sibling) and `#mainbar~div'` (found nothing)

From [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) those spaces are optional, but in fact I got different output with BeautifulSoup for the same selectors (as I thought)

So is it `bs4` bug or this behavior depends on version of CSS or something else?

Comment: Why don't you just not do that? If I inherited code like that it would make me unhappy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is confirmed as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1717851

The selector, from a CSS perspective is fine with/without.

I will see if I can find further evidence.

The individual reporting the bug states:

> The issue, as far as I see, is that since the code is only doing a
>   `shlex.split`, it doesn't treat `div`, `>`, and `span` as separate
>   entities is a space is left out on either side of `>`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, in bug description user gets `ValueError` while I'm just got an empty list... Maybe this was some kind of quick fix for not breaking the scripts...

Comment: I can’t honestly say though sounds plausible. I am looking to see if I can find anything more up to date.

Comment: There is no additional mention in the development log: https://code.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/

Comment: Thank you for help. I just wanted to understand whether bs4 is good for scraping or not.. and as far as I can see - not so good :)

Comment: Bs4 is great for scraping in my limited experience. You just need to remember the spaces it would seem. The appropriate spaces make for more legible selectors.

Comment: There are more ways than just that to do selections with bs4.

Answer (score 2):

in case you want to patch it, see `bs4/element.py` line 1440 replace

```
tokens = shlex.split(selector)
```

with

```
selector = re.sub(r'\s*([+>~])\s*', r' \1 ', selector)
tokens = shlex.split(selector)
```

Demo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
  <code data-type="sample-code">
    import re, shlex

    def testSelect(selector):
        selector = re.sub(r'\s*([+>~])\s*', r' \1 ', selector)
        tokens = shlex.split(selector)
        print(tokens)

    testSelect('#mainbar > div ~ p') # default
    testSelect('#mainbar>div~p')
    testSelect('#mainbar    >div+     p')
    testSelect('#mainbar.classA')
    testSelect('#mainbar p')
  </code>
</div>
```