# same CSS, different outcome in browser and bs4 .select() method

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to retrieve some info from the following web page:
https://web.archive.org/web/19990421025223/http://www.rbc.ru

I constructed a selector which does highlight the desired table in Chrome's  Inspection mode:

```
selector = 'body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody:nth-of-type(1)>tr:nth-of-type(1)>td:nth-of-type(5)>table:nth-of-type(1)>tbody:nth-of-type(1)'
```

however when running a script with bs4 .select() method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/19990421025223/http://www.rbc.ru'
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
    }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
selector = 'body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody:nth-of-type(1)>tr:nth-of-type(1)>td:nth-of-type(5)>table:nth-of-type(1)>tbody:nth-of-type(1)'
print(soup.select(selector=selector))
```

the output is: [] - which is very different from what is expected based on the fact that it consists of html code in browser.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You could not expect the browser-generated selectors to reliably work in `BeautifulSoup` as *when a page is rendered in the browser the markup changes* while when you download a page in your Python code, there is no rendering and you only get the very initial non-rendered HTML page.

Here, you have to come up with your own CSS selector or another way to locate the `table` element.

As the markup of the page is not really HTML-parsing-friendly, I'd locate a `table` element by one of it's column names:

```
table = soup.find("b", text="спрос").find_parent("table")
```

Note that it only worked for me when I parsed the page with a lenient [`html5lib` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Does the first part of it also applies to XPath? Are there any ways ways to virtually render an html code in a browser-ish way and then feed it to BeautifulSoup? Or should I create a new question for such questions?

Comment: @СтепанСмирнов it's better to address this in a separate question, but be careful and make it not broad and on topic. But to give you a short story: yes, you can render a page, you could even automate a real browser, load the page and then parse the rendered page. And, yes, it also applies to auto-generated xpaths. Thanks.

Comment: HTML should always be parsed as HTML anyway. It makes no sense to try and parse it as XML unless you know that the markup you're parsing is XML-serialiized (in which case if the page were not well-formed, it straight up wouldn't render at all). It's like trying to parse German as English (I know XML isn't based on HTML or SGML like English is Germanic but that's not the point) instead of, you know, German.

Comment: Also the name BeautifulSoup is based on "tag soup", a nickname for HTML, which tends to be anything but beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Since at run time javascript can render the entire page differently from the source, `bs4` is not good for websites that changes dynamically.

I would recommend using Selenium, as it actually opens the website, and it allows you to pause the search before certain element gets rendered. There are also other headless browser libraries that emulate the browser environment silently if you don't want to see a browser pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problem in your code, first, in BeautifulSoup if you want to use CSS selector the symbols `+ > ~` need to be separated by `space`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402783/458214) if you want to patch bs4.

Second, as my previous answer to [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544324/) there is no `tbody` in the page source, it generated by browser.

And here fixed CSS selector

```
selector = 'body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(5) > table:nth-of-type(1)'
```

Comment: You mean BeautifulSoup doesn't add the tbody like it's supposed to? That's bad.

Comment: Browsers aren't the only user agents that have to follow the standard when implementing the HTML DOM.

Comment: OK I just noticed that the original code parses the markup in XML mode. *That's* the reason the tbody is not added (and it is correct to do so in that case). Not because "BeautifulSoup is not [a] browser."

Comment: sorry for my bad english :D